# Codeigniter: Couldn't add record into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently following this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/working_with_database.htm

Until these steps, I couldnt add records into database, I'm very new into Codeigniter.

Stud_controller.php

```
<?php 
   class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->database(); 
      } 

      public function index() { 
         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 

         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function add_student_view() {       
        $this->load->helper('form'); 
        $this->load->view('Stud_add'); 
      } 

      public function add_student() {
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $this->Stud_Model->insert($data); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student_view() { 
         $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         $query = $this->db->get_where("stud",array("roll_no"=>$roll_no));
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $data['old_roll_no'] = $roll_no; 
         $this->load->view('Stud_edit',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student(){ 
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
         $this->Stud_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function delete_student() { 
         $this->load->model('Stud_Model'); 
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         $this->Stud_Model->delete($roll_no); 

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

Stud_Model.php

```
<?php 
   class Stud_Model extends CI_Model {

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
      } 

      public function insert($data) { 
         if ($this->db->insert("stud", $data)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
      } 

      public function delete($roll_no) { 
         if ($this->db->delete("stud", "roll_no = ".$roll_no)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
      } 

      public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
         $this->db->set($data); 
         $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
         $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

Student_add.php (view)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
      <title>Students Example</title> 
   </head> 

   <body> 
      <form method = "" action = "">

         <?php 
            echo form_open('Stud_controller/add_student');
            echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no')); 
            echo "<br/>"; 

            echo form_label('Name'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name')); 
            echo "<br/>"; 

            echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Add')); 
            echo form_close(); 
         ?> 

      </form> 
   </body>

</html>
```

I dont think there's a routing problem because the delete function is working.

Comment: It's so much errors and bad practice... try starting to remove the form tag, the form_open already do that and report

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre do you mean form_label, form_input etc?

Comment: Tip: You need to make sure your filename and class names have first letter upper case only rest lower case https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming. Also on controllers and models you dont need to end file with `?>` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Don't load model every function you create, for God's sake. Use construct instead.

[Check CI Controller pattern too](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html), does not need controller name, your route will be so ugly with that.

I changed the [model calling, it's other pattern](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) you need attention too.

```
<?php 
   class Stud extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper('url', 'form'); //prefer to put the basics helpers on autoload in config dir, you will use basically in all your project 
         $this->load->database(); //you don't need that, just check your confs
         $this->load->model('stud_model'); //check the needs of this model too. If it's too basic, put on autoload
      } 

      public function index() { 
         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 

         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function add_student_view() {       
        $this->load->view('Stud_add'); 
      } 

      public function add_student() {
         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $this->stud_model->insert($data); //avoid camelcase and stuff into model object call 
         //dont use db access inside controller, this behavior is from model, create a Get function there
         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student_view() {  
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         //dont use db access inside controller, this behavior is from model, create a Get function there

         $query = $this->db->get_where("stud",array("roll_no"=>$roll_no));
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $data['old_roll_no'] = $roll_no; 
         $this->load->view('Stud_edit',$data); 
      } 

      public function update_student(){ 

         $data = array( 
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
            'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
         ); 

         $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
         $this->stud_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 
             //dont use db access inside controller, this behavior is from model, create a Get function there

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 

      public function delete_student() { 
         $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
         $this->stud_model->delete($roll_no); 
             //dont use db access inside controller, this behavior is from model, create a Get function there

         $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
         $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
         $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
      } 
   } 
?>

<?php 
   class Stud_Model extends CI_Model {
   //create Get and Set functions with private variables
      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
      } 

      public function insert($data) { 
         if ($this->db->insert("stud", $data)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
       //use try/catch, avoid only ifs with returns
      } 

      public function delete($roll_no) { 
         if ($this->db->delete("stud", "roll_no = ".$roll_no)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
       //use try/catch, avoid only ifs with returns
      } 

      public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
         $this->db->set($data); 
         $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
         $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
      } 
   } 
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
      <title>Students Example</title> 
   </head> 

   <body> 

         <?php 
            echo form_open('stud/add_student'); //check this route
            echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no','name'=>'roll_no')); 
            echo "<br/>"; 

            echo form_label('Name'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name')); 
            echo "<br/>"; 

            echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Add')); 
            echo form_close(); 
         ?> 
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I followed your suggestion to use construct and renaming the model and controller. also I checked the routes, everything seemed right (the delete function is working). could you explain to me what try/catch to use??

Comment: Welcome. If you changed the controller name, check the form_open. I reviewed everything here and is alright. Can you put your updated code in the end of your question to me analyze him?